# Escape Pipe in SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a pipe delimited file which has to be loaded via SQL*Loader in Oracle.

My control file looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  ID   "TRIM(:ID)",
  TEXT "NVL(TRIM(:TEXT),' ')"
)
```

The TEXT column in the data file can contain text with "|"- i.e., delimiter too.

How can I accept pipe in the TEXT column?

Comment: Are the fields which can include a pipe as part of the value enclosed, e.g. in double-quotes? (See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-0DE2F816-CF31-4806-891C-05D3C548B34B) for how termination and enclosure work.)

Comment: No the fields are  not enclosed.

Comment: Is it necessary to enclose the fields in some other delimiter to accept Terminated By delimiter in data ? Is there a way to send just the  |( pipe) enclosed in or using some characters to escape it and not to use Optionally Enclosed by or Enclosed By options ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't escape the delimiter; but if you want everything up to the first pipe to be the `ID` and everything after the first pipe to be `TEXT`, you could treat the record in the data file as a single field and split it using SQL functions, e.g.:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE ...
REPLACE
INTO TABLE TABLE1
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  ID   CHAR(4000) "regexp_replace(:ID, '^(.*?)(\\|(.*))?$', '\\1')",
  TEXT EXPRESSION "regexp_replace(:ID, '^(.*?)(\\|(.*))?$', '\\3')"
)
```

There is no `FIELDS` clause.

The `ID` is initially up to 4000 characters from the line (just a large value to hopefully capture any data you have). A regex replace is then applied to that; the pattern defines a first group as any characters (non-greedy), optionally followed by a second group comprising a pipe and a third inner group of zero or more characters after that pipe. The original value is replaced by group 1.

The `TEXT` is defined as an `EXPRESSION`, meaning it isn't obtained directly from the file; instead the same regex pattern is applied to the *original* `ID` value, but now that is replaced by the *third* group, which is everything after the first pipe (if there is one).

An equivalent in plain SQL as a demo would be:

```sql
with data (id) as (
  select '123|test 1' from dual
  union all
  select '234|test 2|with pipe' from dual
  union all
  select '345|test 3|with|multiple|pipes|' from dual
  union all
  select null from dual
  union all
  select '678' from dual
  union all
  select '789|' from dual
)
select id as original,
  regexp_replace(ID, '^(.*?)(\|(.*))?$', '\1') as id,
  regexp_replace(ID, '^(.*?)(\|(.*))?$', '\3') as text
from data;
```

which gives:

```
ORIGINAL                        ID   TEXT                         
------------------------------- ---- ------------------------------
123|test 1                      123  test 1                       
234|test 2|with pipe            234  test 2|with pipe             
345|test 3|with|multiple|pipes| 345  test 3|with|multiple|pipes|  
                                                                  
567                             567                               
678|                            678
```

If you don't need to worry about records without that first pipe, or with that first pipe but followed by nothing, then the regex could be simpler:

```
(
  ID   CHAR(4000) "regexp_replace(:ID, '^(.*?)\\|(.*)$', '\\1')",
  TEXT EXPRESSION "regexp_replace(:ID, '^(.*?)\\|(.*)$', '\\2')"
)
```